404 Page in Angular is not routable with localization (** can't be resolved)
I have an application built for (currently) two languages. German and English. I am also trying to Route some pages like about, home, login, etc... But I am facing one issue I just can't resolve. If no language is given on visit and a non acceptable route is entered in the url bar (example.com/unknown) I get the Netlify not found window. Even with my routes set up.
It only accepts example.com/en|de/unknown and will resolve the 404 route.
| ... standing for "or" in this case
Routes:
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutEduguardComponent },
  { path: 'download', component: DownloadComponent },
  { path: 'license', component: GetLicenceComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' },
];

I have tried many things, that ended up with the same result. Like removeing i18n and redoing everything configurating a baseHref with no change, etc...

Sounds like you have two applications served at example.com/en and example.com/de. If that's the case, you can't resolve this in Angular's routing; you'll need to tell Netlify what to do with requests to /example (probably just redirect them to /en/example where Angular can take over and redirect to /en/404).

Thank you, I initially thought that the /de and /en sites are managed from angular but that makes sence, because in the dist folder there is no html file. in the root
